# MYSQLI - PHP : Display products page issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a admin insert products page,
i am trying to create a display products page so all users who visit the website can see the products. I am trying to layout all the data exactly the same so when a new product is inserted into the website it looks the same as the others, and no need to add styles or create a new layout each time.

But i am having no luck, i have tried two different ways, but nothing at all is displaying.

Attempt 1:

```
     <?php
    $select_prods = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM Rest_Details");
    while($row_prods = $select_prods->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['rest_name'] = $row_prods['Resturant_name'];
    $_SESSION['rest_name'] = $row_prods['Resturant_name'];
    $_SESSION['rest_addlin1'] = $row_prods['Res_Address_Line_1'];
    $_SESSION['rest_addlin2'] = $row_prods['Res_Address_Line_2'];
    $_SESSION['rest_city'] = $row_prods['City_name'];
    $_SESSION['rest_pcode'] = $row_prods['Resturant_Postcode'];
    $_SESSION['rest_avg'] = $row_prods['Avg_Del'];
    $_SESSION['rest_Est_Del'] = $row_prods['Est_Del'];

    echo "
          <div id='products_box'>

    <p id='name'> $_SESSION['rest_name']</p>
     </div>
        "
      }
```

Attempt 2

```
           <?php
        $select_prods = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Details";
        //$run_prods = mysqli_query($dbc, $select_prods);
        $run_prods = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $select_prods) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        while ($row_prods = mysqli_fetch_array($run_prods)) {
            $rest_id = $row_prods['Resturant_ID'];
            $rest_name = $row_prods['Resturant_name'];
            $rest_add = $row_prods['Res_Address_Line_1'];
            $rest_city = $row_prods['City_name'];

            echo "

   <div id='product'>
        <h3>$rest_name </h3> 
        <p>$rest_add</p>
        <a href='product_page.php'><button>Feed Me!</button></a>    
    </div>
   ";
        }
    ?>
```

For both i expect to see product name, address, average delivery time ... but nothing at all displays.

Both the querys work, is there a better way to display all the content, so all products look the same and on a new product insert that also has the same layout and displays the same information such as product name, address, average delivery time ...

any suggestions will help

Comment: Please add the expected result, e.g. what you want to happen, and the actual result, e.g. what actually happens, in both scenarios.

Comment: You shouldn't go with the first example. Basically you are rewriting the `$_SESSION` global variable for each iteration of the while loop. The second example should work as expected, so I'm not sure what you're trying to get at?

Comment: I think you're missing a few function calls to `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`, and `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`

Comment: @Terry the second example is not displaying anything at all. Where as the first is

Comment: Is there any reason you're stuffing everything into `$_SESSION`? That should be used for data persisted between requests, and used sparingly. Cluttering it up with temporary things is a bad plan.

Comment: @jerneva use ' ; ' at the end of the echo statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Details";
        $query = $dbc->query($sql);
        while ( $products = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query) ) {
            $rest_id   = $products['Resturant_ID'];
            $rest_name = $products['Resturant_name'];
            $rest_add  = $products['Res_Address_Line_1'];
            $rest_city = $products['City_name'];  
            echo $rest_id.'<br>'; 
            echo $rest_name.'<br>';  
            echo $rest_add.'<br>';  
            echo $rest_city.'<br>'; 
        } 
?>
```